# Class fields in Ruby (mongoid?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I found the following piece of code:

```
  class Store
    include ::Mongoid::Document
    include ::Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :cache_class, type: String

    index({cache_class: 1, key: 1}, {background: true})

    validates :cache_class, presence: true
  end
```

Are `field` and `validates` method calls? If so, can anyone explain me this ruby syntax?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an embedded domain specific language (Embedded DSL or just EDSL). `field`, `index` and `validates` are class methods, that configure the behavior of the future objects. This syntax shouldn't look like peace of program. Instead it should look like a configuration language.

Those methods are normally defined in one of included classes (`::Mongoid::Document` or `::Mongoid::Timestamps` in this case).

This pattern is pretty common in ruby.